# XCode 7: code editor in "full screen" mode shortcut

Tags: ios, xcode

There is a shortcut in XCode to make the code editor (or at least, the current focused window panel) full screen*? In Netbeans, this functionality is achieved with `shift+esc`: the focused panel expands, hiding other panels.

Thanks in advance.

*Not in the sense of "full screen" Mac OS feature, but the editor panel takes all the visible area, hiding other panels (like the Navigation panel, Property panel, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new Behavior and assign a shortcut to it. At the top menu, select **Xcode > Behaviors > Edit Behaviors...**:

[image: Xcode Behaviors]

In the screenshot, I assigned it a shortcut key of `Cmd + Esc` but you can choose anything you want.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But I have to add an Exit Full Screen shortcut to restore. Shortcut does not perform toggle.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not one button to do it all.

You can double click on the file and it will open a new editor window with just the text.

These three combinations will close each of the major three panels:

Command + 0 - Hide/show the Navigator

Shift + Command + Y - Hide/Show the Debug area

Alt + Command + 0 - Hide/Show the Utilities

- You can change these in XCode -> Preferences -> Key Bindings